# C# algorithm refactor splitting an array into 3 parts?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, loops

I have an IEnumerable and I wanted to split the data across 3 columns using the following business logic. if 3 or less items, 1 item per column, anything else I wanted to divide the total items by 3 split the leftovers (either 1 or 2 items) between the first two columns. Now this is pretty ugly but it does the job. I'm looking for tips to leverage linq a little better or possibly eliminate the switch statement. Any advice or tips that improve the code are appreciated.

```
var numItems = items.Count;

            IEnumerable<JToken> col1Items,
                                col2Items, 
                                col3Items;


            if(numItems <=3)
            {
                col1Items = items.Take(1);
                col2Items = items.Skip(1).Take(1);
                col3Items = items.Skip(2).Take(1);

            } else {

                int remainder = numItems % 3,
                    take = numItems / 3,
                    col1Take, 
                    col2Take, 
                    col3Take;

                switch(remainder)
                {
                    case 1:
                        col1Take = take + 1;
                        col2Take = take;
                        col3Take = take;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        col1Take = take + 1;
                        col2Take = take + 1;
                        col3Take = take;
                        break;
                    default:
                        col1Take = take;
                        col2Take = take;
                        col3Take = take;
                        break;

                }

                col1Items = items.Take(col1Take);
                col2Items = items.Skip(col1Take).Take(col2Take);
                col3Items = items.Skip(col1Take + col2Take).Take(col3Take);
```

Ultimately I am using these in a mvc Razor view

```
<div class="widgetColumn">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => col1Items, "MenuColumn")                       
            </div> 

            <div class="widgetColumn">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => col2Items, "MenuColumn")                       
            </div> 

            <div class="widgetColumn">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => col3Items, "MenuColumn")                       
            </div>
```

In my first attempt I want to get rid of the colNItems and colNTake variables but i can't figure out the correct algorithm to make it work the same.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++ )
            {
                IEnumerable<JToken> widgets = new List<JToken>();
                var col = i;
                switch(col)
                {
                    case 1:
                       break;
                    case 2:
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Think recursive! the leftover rule is in principle the same as the 'lesser than 3' rule which in turn is similar to divide rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generalize:

```
int cols = 3;
IEnumerable<JToken> colItems[3]; // you can make this dynamic of course

int rem = numItems % cols;
int len = numItems / cols;

for (int col=0; col<cols; col++){
    int colTake = len;
    if (col < rem) colTake++;
    colItems[col] = items.Skip(col*len).Take(colTake);
}
```

Haven't tested, but this should work for any number of columns.

Also whenever you need variables col1, col2, col3 think of col[0], col[1], col[2].

Comment: This does not create 3 lists?

Comment: Code now creates the lists. Also I believe it's in line with the OP's idea of keeping the consecutive elements in the same column

Comment: I ended up using this approach. Seemed clean and simple enough. All great solutions though everyone. I definitely like the pure css approach from Brian Ball as well. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 6):

Are the columns fixed-width? If so, then there's no need to do anything special with your collection. Just rely on the browser to do it for you. Have an outer container that has the overall width of the 3 columns, then just fill it with a div for each item (and float left). Set your inner containers to have a width exactly 1/3 of the outer container.

Here's a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YTqE4/)

Here's a quick hint at the style

```
div#outer{
    width:300px;    
}

div#outer > div{
    width:100px;
    float:left;    
}
```

Comment: Regarding this solution, they wanted the items "vertically" sliced if you will, as in items 1-whatever would show up in the same column, not  horizontal as in the fiddle. Great solution though!!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do something like?

```
int len = numItems / 3;
int rem = numItems % 3;

int col1Take = len + (rem > 0 ? 1 : 0);
int col2Take = len + (rem > 1 ? 1 : 0);
int col3Take = len;
```

**Edit:**

A more generic solution that works for any number of columns (`COLUMNS`) would be:

```
int len = numItems / COLUMNS;
int rem = numItems % COLUMNS;

foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, COLUMNS)) {
  colTake[i] = len + (rem > i ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense, are you just counting the items?  Don't you want to put the result in a list?

Comment: If you read the entirety of the original post you'll see that the question is "is there a way to get rid of the switch statement?". I've done that with this code snippet.

Comment: I see what you mean, however I think he needs a solution that makes the lists faster.

Comment: I assume performance is not the issue (since it rarely *really* is). Instead, I focus on maintainability, re-usability, and bad-code-smells. I posted the first solution because it is really maintainable and addresses the worst of the code smells, but the second solution trades some readability for re-usability, so I went ahead and included that as well. To each their own.

Comment: No Hogan performance was not an issue in this case. The outer collection would never have more than 20-30 items. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

So you want the first n/3 items in the first column, next n/3 items in the 2nd column, etc.

```
var concreteList = items.ToList();
var count = concreteList.Count;
var take1 = count/3 + (count % 3 > 0 ? 1 : 0);
var take2 = count/3 + (count % 3 > 1 ? 1 : 0);

var col1 = concreteList.Take(take1);
var col2 = concreteList.Skip(take1).Take(take2);
var col3 = concreteList.Skip(take1 + take2);
```

I make a concrete list in order to avoid iterating the `Enumerable` multiple times. For example, if you had:

```
items = File.ReadLines("foo.txt");
```

Then you wouldn't be able to iterate it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill the columns round-robin you can use:

```
int numColumns = 3;

var result = Enumerable.Range(1,numColumns).Select(c =>
      items.Where((x,ix) => ix % numColumns == c-1).ToArray()
   );
```

Comment: cute, but you do iterate the list 3 times instead of once.

Answer (score 0):

it might help

```
        IEnumerable<object> items = new Object[]{ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7","8", "9", "10", "11", "12","13", "14" };

        IEnumerable<object> col1Items = new List<object>(),
                            col2Items = new List<object>(), 
                            col3Items = new List<object>();

        Object[] list = new Object[]{col1Items, col2Items, col3Items};
        int limit = items.Count()/3;
        int len = items.Count();
        int col;            

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++ )
        {                
            if (len == 3) col = i;
            else col = i / limit;

            if (col >= 3) col = i%limit ;

            ((IList<object>)(list[col])).Add( items.ElementAt(i));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't fast, but it'll do the trick:

```
var col1Items = items.Select((obj, index) => new { Value = obj, Index = index })
    .Where(o => o.Index % 3 == 0).Select(o => o.Value);
var col2Items = items.Select((obj, index) => new { Value = obj, Index = index })
    .Where(o => o.Index % 3 == 1).Select(o => o.Value);
var col3Items = items.Select((obj, index) => new { Value = obj, Index = index })
    .Where(o => o.Index % 3 == 2).Select(o => o.Value);
```

It uses the version of Select that includes an index parameter.  You could use a GroupBy to speed this up a bit at the cost of a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go across then down see answer below this one, if you want to go down then across you can do it like this (use this code with the test below to see it working instead of the `var result` line there.:

```
var curCol = 0;
var iPer = items.Count() / 3;
var iLeft = items.Count() % 3;
var result = items.Aggregate(
               // object that will hold items
               new {  
                      cols = new List<ItemElement>[3] { new List<ItemElement>(), 
                                                        new List<ItemElement>(), 
                                                        new List<ItemElement>(), },
                          },
               (o, n) => {
                 o.cols[curCol].Add(n);

                 if (o.cols[curCol].Count() > iPer + (iLeft > (curCol+1) ? 1:0))
                   curCol++;

                 return new {
                   cols = o.cols
                };
             });
```

You can do this with aggregate.  It would look like this:

```
void Main()
{
  List<ItemElement> items = new List<ItemElement>() { 
           new ItemElement() { aField = 1 },
           new ItemElement() { aField = 2 },
           new ItemElement() { aField = 3 },
           new ItemElement() { aField = 4 },
           new ItemElement() { aField = 5 },
           new ItemElement() { aField = 6 },
           new ItemElement() { aField = 7 },
           new ItemElement() { aField = 8 },
           new ItemElement() { aField = 9 }
  };

  var result = 
    items.Aggregate(
      // object that will hold items
      new {  
        cols = new List<ItemElement>[3] { new List<ItemElement>(), 
                                          new List<ItemElement>(), 
                                          new List<ItemElement>(), },
        next = 0 },
     // aggregate
     (o, n) => {
       o.cols[o.next].Add(n);

       return new {
         cols = o.cols,
         next = (o.next + 1) % 3
       };
    });
  result.Dump();
}

public class ItemElement 
{
   public int aField { get; set; }
}
```

You end up with an object with an array of 3 lists (one for each column).

This example will run as is in linqPad.  I recomment linqPad for these kind of POC tests. (linqPad.com)

Answer (score 0):

LinqLib (nuget: LinqExtLibrary) has an overload of ToArray() that does it:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using LinqLib.Array;

...

    public void TakeEm(IEnumerable<int> data)
    {
        var dataAry = data as int[] ?? data.ToArray();
        var rows = (dataAry.Length/3) + 1;
        //var columns = Enumerable.Empty<int>().ToArray(3, rows);
        // vvv These two lines are the ones that re-arrange your array
        var columns = dataAry.ToArray(3, rows);
        var menus = columns.Slice();
    }
```